# Django import in template

Tags: django, paginator

I know how to paginate in a function view or CBV, but that doesn't help here.

The POC model has a foreign key pointing to the `Tag` model.
In the `Tag` detail template, I want to show all the POCs that point to that `Tag`.

```
{% for poc in tag.poc_set.all|dictsort:"name" %}
```

The problem is that there are thousands. Can I import `Paginator` in the template and construct a `Paginator` passing `tag.poc_set.all` to the constructor (or "wrap" the queryset in a `Paginator` - excuse my javaspeak)?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. In your view pass the template a page instead of the entire queryset.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/#module-django.core.paginator

Answer (score 0):

Handle the queryset in your view:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage

AMOUNT_LISTED_POC = 10 # This determines how many POC that you want to display per page
all_poc = tag.poc_set.all().order_by('name')

page = request.GET.get("page",1)
if page:
    paginator = Paginator(all_poc,AMOUNT_LISTED_POC)
    try:
        all_poc = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        all_poc = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        all_poc = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Comment: Gratias.I see you meant AMOUNT_LISTED_POC.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it works, but if you want to access the queryset itself, create a new variable with the same : global_poc = all_poc. I am telling that you because in my case, i wanted to show the count() object in the template. It would not work with pagination object. but if you keep the queryset in other variable, you will be able
global_poc.count() will be the global sum
all_poc.count or all_poc|length will always remain the amount which is displayed